# How to setup and connect my database to NodeJS application on digital ocean

Tags: mysql, node.js, digital-ocean, database-cluster

I have managed to create a droplet on Digital-Ocean and managed to clone my Node JS app onto it. Locally , the app connects to MySQL database and I wanted to the same on the live version. Ignorantly, I attempted to create a Managed database cluster which I did and added 1 user account and created 1 database. Right now I do not know how I can import the exported `database.sql` file into the database since I am only used to phpMyAdmin.

How can I get this to work and connect to my NodeJS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your database cluster is not open to the outside world by adding a DB firewall using DigitalOcean databases. You can allow connections from your own droplet's private IP address, and your own public address (or VPN or however way you're set up). Once you've done that, you should be able to import your SQL file locally (or from the DO Droplet, as long as you have the mysql client installed):

```
mysql -h [host-provided-do] -P [port-provided-do] -u [username-provided-do] -p [db-name-provided-do] < my-file.sql
```

The most important thing is to make sure your managed database is not open to the outside world, and that you make sure it only allows incoming connections from known IP addresses.

In your NodeJS app, you can set the driver to connect to the private subnet that DO provides.

Comment: I have tries this using mysql client install on my local machine, I am getting the following error:```ERROR 3750 (HY000) at line 31: Unable to create or change a table without a primary key, when the system variable 'sql_require_primary_key' is set. Add a primary key to the table or unset this variable to avoid this message. Note that tables without a primary key can cause performance problems in row-based replication, so please consult your DBA before changing this setting.```

Comment: It's well explained in their documentation: "MySQL databases containing tables without a primary key and which contain more than 5000 rows may experience replication issues. To prevent this, DigitalOcean now requires you to add a primary key for each new table you create in any managed MySQL database created after 8 April 2020". https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/mysql/. So, you need to create a primary key on all tables

Comment: I think you can change the session variable and it'd be OK, but highly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You were using `phpmyadmin` as an interactive Mysql client program. It's easy to use but hard to set up because it's a web app.

Try another MySql client program. The command-line client, memorably named `mysql`, is a good choice.

Get a shell on your droplet, then say

```
sudo apt install -y mysql-client
mysql -u username -p -h databasehostname -D database
mysql> source database.sql
mysql> quit
```

You'll be prompted for your database password.

That should import your database.

The `mysql` command line program is very useful and worth some of your time to learn to use.